# Review of Hammock setup sketch

Tags: camping, wild-camping, hammock

I'm trying to visualise how to setup my first hammock and what kit I will need (excluding tarp and underlay) can you check my sketch below (excuse the simplistic style) and confirm that I have covered all the basics

[image]

Comment: FYI *Knot that moves but locks under weight* would be a [Prusik](http://www.animatedknots.com/prusik/#ScrollPoint) of some description

Comment: @Liam thank you, that's going to be really useful

Comment: A prussic is one of many friction hitches, there are multiple ways to tie a friction hitch.